# Spring cloud config server. Environment variables in properties

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-config

I configured Spring Cloud Config server like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServer.class, args);
    }
}
```

I'm using 'native' profile so properties are picked up from the file system:

```
server.port=8888
spring.profiles.active=native
spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations: classpath:/global
```

Now the tricky part is that some properties contain **environmental variables**. Properties in 'global/application-production.properties' are configured like this:

```
test=${DOCKER_HOST}
```

When I start up Config Server - everything works fine. However when I access http://localhost:8888/testapp/production I see this:

```
{
    name: "testapp",
    profiles: [
        "production"
],
    label: null,
    version: null,
    propertySources: [
        {
            name: "classpath:/global/application-production.properties",
            source: {
                test: "${DOCKER_HOST}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So value from ENV variable is not replacing ${DOCKER_HOST} put rather returned as is.

But if I access http://localhost:8888/application-production.properties then result is non JSON but rather plain text:

```
test: tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
```

Spring documentation says:

> The YAML and properties representations have an additional flag (provided as a boolean query parameter resolvePlaceholders) to signal that placeholders in the source documents, in the standard Spring ${…​} form, should be resolved in the output where possible before rendering. This is a useful feature for consumers that don’t know about the Spring placeholder conventions.

For some reason **resolvePlaceholders** is not working for JSON representation thus server config clients need to be aware of all ENV variables configured on server.

Is it possible to force JSON representation **resolvePlaceholders** same way as plain text (properties) representation?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. After looking into Spring Cloud Config Repository I have found the following commit:
[Omit system properties and env vars from placeholders in config](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/commit/f8fc4e19375d3b4c0c2562a71bc49ba288197100)

It looks like such behavior is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the [Property Overrides](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_property_overrides) feature to override properties from git Environment Repository.

To override property `foo` at runtime, just set a system property or an environment variable `spring.cloud.config.server.overrides.foo` before starting the config server.

Answer (score 0):

There was an update in order to accomplish this, in the following merge. [1](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/commit/53e049a8123a78b6bb2ef1ec550e216829bc1436#diff-14e7f2c355ba7a1946cf8c845605b698) I found an implementation for `resolvePlaceholders`. Which gave me the idea of just creating a new controller which uses the `EnvironmentController`. This will allow you to resolve configuration, this is a good bootstrap.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentRepository;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = "resolved/${spring.cloud.config.server.prefix:}")
public class ReplacedEnvironmentController {

  private EnvironmentController  environmentController;

  @Autowired
  public ReplacedEnvironmentController(EnvironmentRepository repository) {
    environmentController = new EnvironmentController(repository, new ObjectMapper());
  }

  public ReplacedEnvironmentController(EnvironmentRepository repository,
      ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    environmentController = new EnvironmentController(repository, objectMapper);

  }

  @RequestMapping("/{name}/{profiles:.*[^-].*}")
  public ResponseEntity<String> resolvedDefaultLabel(@PathVariable String name,
      @PathVariable String profiles) throws Exception  {
    return resolvedLabelled(name, profiles, null);
  }

  @RequestMapping("/{name}/{profiles}/{label:.*}")
  public ResponseEntity<String> resolvedLabelled(@PathVariable String name, @PathVariable String profiles,
      @PathVariable String label) throws Exception  {
    return environmentController.labelledJsonProperties(name, profiles, label, true);
  }

}
```