# Spring Config Server - resolvePlaceholders + enviroment variables

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-config

I've got question about resolving environment variables in shared files of config server. 
My current setup is pretty minimal :

1. **src/main/resources/shared/application.yml** :

   application:
     version: 0.0.1-early
     test: ${JAVA_HOME}
2. **src/main/resources/application.properties** :

   spring.profiles.active=native
   spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=classpath:/shared
3. **Using gradle with :**

   - spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE
   - spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.SR7
   - And then of course compile 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server' in deps

**Problem :** 
**GET http://localhost:8888/apptest/application** gives me :

```
{
    "name": "apptest",
    "profiles": [
        "application"
    ],
    "label": null,
    "version": null,
    "state": null,
    "propertySources": [
        {
            "name": "classpath:/shared/application.yml",
            "source": {
                "application.version": "0.0.1-early",
                "application.test": "${JAVA_HOME}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So env variable is not resolved. Same thing is with :

- http://localhost:8888/apptest/application?resolvePlaceholders=true
- http://localhost:8888/lab/apptest-application.properties?resolvePlaceholders=true
- http://localhost:8888/lab/apptest-application.properties?resolvePlaceholders=false
- http://localhost:8888/apptest-application.properties?resolvePlaceholders=true

I've looked at [Spring cloud config server. Environment variables in properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751311/spring-cloud-config-server-environment-variables-in-properties) but solution didn't help me + there where few new versions since then. So I'm opening new question.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's not a bug and everything is fine. I did not understood how Config server works.

1. `http://localhost:8888/apptest/application` - returns yet not resolved value of *${JAVA_HOME}*
2. When we get ei. into container *"C"* that pings Config Service for configuration and do `curl http://config:8888/apptest/application` we get the same - unresolved *${JAVA_HOME}*
3. But when we look into Spring application ei. in container "C" and try to inject `@Value("${application.test}")` somewhere, we get proper value or info that env variable was not set.

**It means that environment variables are resolved on client side.**
 Thanks to that I've understood how NOT production ready env_variables approach is.

Answer (score 0):

Well the changes happened here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/commit/f8fc4e19375d3b4c0c2562a71bc49ba288197100 that removes the support of replacing the environment variables.

You can always add a new controller and override the behaviour of the `EnvironmentPropertySource#prepareEnvironment`