# In spring, what's the difference between putting a property in jvm properties and bootstrap.yml?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I know bootstrap properties are used in the bootstrapping phase before the application yml is loaded as per [What is the difference between putting a property on application.yml or bootstrap.yml in spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997352/what-is-the-difference-between-putting-a-property-on-application-yml-or-bootstra)

However, I don't understand how adding a property using jvm options or system properties relates to these phases.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751311/spring-cloud-config-server-environment-variables-in-properties) provides some hints

Comment: [Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#:~:text=Spring%20Boot%20lets%20you%20externalize,line%20arguments%20to%20externalize%20configuration.) is documentation about external configuration, hopefully, it would help you.